# Quarkus - how to use OpenAPI generated API as Quarkus rest client?

Tags: openapi, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have YAML definition from another project which will generate an `ExternalAPI.java` for me. I am using OpenAPI plugin of Maven.

Now, I also can do `@RestClient` in Quarkus, defining `@RegisterRestClient(configKey="foo")` and enable injection; also, `@RegisterClientHeaders` to inject some header.

Now, how to combine both? I want to keep using the annotations I mentioned, while making use of the generated API class.

---

Now, I am using `RestClientBuilder`:

```java
RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .baseUri(new URI(someUrl))
        .register((ClientRequestFilter) context -> context.getHeaders().put("MyToken", Collections.singletonList(token)))
        .build(ExternalAPI.class);
```

Usable, but little bit strange; I need to create the instance myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create an interface that extends the generated `ExternalAPI` interface and annotate it with `@RegisterRestClient` and `@RegisterClientHeaders`

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey="foo")
@RegisterClientHeaders(MyHeadersFactory.class)
public interface MyExternalAPI extends ExternalAPI {
// define something
}
```

and now inject it in any service

```
public class MyService {
    @Inject
    MyExternalAPI externalAPI;

    public void doSomething() {
        // use the externalAPI instance
    }
}
```

Now you can use the annotations you mentioned and make use of the generated API class. Quarkus will handle the instantiation of `MyExternalAPI` for you.

Comment: This works for me, thanks. Even though I think this is a workaround and inheritance is not what I prefer, it is a solution. Additionally it solves RESTEASY004687 problem(Quarkus not closing the RestClient built underneath).

Comment: it's an honor that you got the answer

Comment: One thing to add is that, `@Produces` and `@Consumes` added to the extended class does **NOT** really changes the `Content-Type` and `Accept` header of request, if they specify a different value than the super one. If you want to change these headers, they need to be added explicitly.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The `@Produces` and `@Consumes` annotations are used to specify the media types that a REST endpoint can produce or consume. However, they do not automatically change the Content-Type and Accept headers of the request or response.
```
type = "Content-Type", "application/json"
or type = "Accept", "application/xml" ````

(that's not how  we declare the variable in Java, That's just an example)

for that purpose you just need to change the ```target.request().header(<type>).<request<get, post>>()```

Answer (score 2):

This was impl. in April 2023 :
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/32880
(Was not impl./available at the time when the question was asked here)

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially asking for [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/32189) feature.
Unfortunately it has not yet been implemented.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know that there is already an issue created for the dev team; but the link is not visible for me at this moment, it shows "Looks like something went wrong!"

Comment: Yeah, Github is experiencing an outage as we write